# NumPy: calculate cumulative median

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, vectorization

I have sample with size = n.

I want to calculate for each i: 1 <= i <= n  median for `sample[:i]` in numpy.
For example, I counted mean for each i:

`cummean = np.cumsum(sample) / np.arange(1, n + 1)`

Can I do something similar for the median without cycles and comprehension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach that replicates elements along rows to give us a `2D` array. Then, we would fill the upper triangular region with a big number so that later on when we sort the array along each row, would basically sort all elements till the diagonal elements and that simulates the cumulative windows. Then, following the definition of `median` that chooses the middle one or the mean of two middle ones (for even no. of elements), we would get the elements at the first position : `(0,0)`, then for the second row : mean of `(1,0) & (1,1)`, for the third row : `(2,1)`, for the fourth row : mean of `(3,1) & (3,2)` and so on. So, we will extract out those elements from the sorted array and thus have our median values.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
def cummedian_sorted(a):
    n = a.size
    maxn = a.max()+1
    a_tiled_sorted = np.tile(a,n).reshape(-1,n)
    mask = np.triu(np.ones((n,n),dtype=bool),1)

    a_tiled_sorted[mask] = maxn
    a_tiled_sorted.sort(1)

    all_rows = a_tiled_sorted[np.arange(n), np.arange(n)//2].astype(float)
    idx = np.arange(1,n,2)
    even_rows = a_tiled_sorted[idx, np.arange(1,1+(n//2))]
    all_rows[idx] += even_rows
    all_rows[1::2] /= 2.0
    return all_rows
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
# Loopy solution from @Uriel's soln   
def cummedian_loopy(arr):
    return [median(a[:i]) for i in range(1,len(a)+1)]

# Nan-fill based solution from @Nickil Maveli's soln   
def cummedian_nanfill(arr):
    a = np.tril(arr).astype(float)
    a[np.triu_indices(a.shape[0], k=1)] = np.nan
    return np.nanmedian(a, axis=1)
```

Timings -

Set #1 :

```
In [43]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,(100))

In [44]: print np.allclose(cummedian_loopy(a), cummedian_sorted(a))
    ...: print np.allclose(cummedian_loopy(a), cummedian_nanfill(a))
    ...: 
True
True

In [45]: %timeit cummedian_loopy(a)
    ...: %timeit cummedian_nanfill(a)
    ...: %timeit cummedian_sorted(a)
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 856 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 778 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 200 µs per loop
```

Set #2 :

```
In [46]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000))

In [47]: print np.allclose(cummedian_loopy(a), cummedian_sorted(a))
    ...: print np.allclose(cummedian_loopy(a), cummedian_nanfill(a))
    ...: 
True
True

In [48]: %timeit cummedian_loopy(a)
    ...: %timeit cummedian_nanfill(a)
    ...: %timeit cummedian_sorted(a)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 118 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 47.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 18.8 ms per loop
```

Set #3 :

```
In [49]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,(5000))

In [50]: print np.allclose(cummedian_loopy(a), cummedian_sorted(a))
    ...: print np.allclose(cummedian_loopy(a), cummedian_nanfill(a))

True
True

In [54]: %timeit cummedian_loopy(a)
    ...: %timeit cummedian_nanfill(a)
    ...: %timeit cummedian_sorted(a)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 3.36 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 583 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 521 ms per loop
```

Comment: I got faster times for `loopy`, but I was using `np.median`, not the stats one.

Answer (score 6):

Knowing that Python has a `heapq` module that lets you keep a running 'minimum' for an iterable, I did a search on `heapq` and `median`, and found various items for `steaming medium`.  This one:

http://www.ardendertat.com/2011/11/03/programming-interview-questions-13-median-of-integer-stream/

has a `class streamMedian` that maintains two `heapq`, one with the bottom half of the values, the other with top half.  The median is either the 'top' of one or the mean of values from both.  The class has an `insert` method and a `getMedian` method.  Most of the work is in the `insert`.

I copied that into an Ipython session, and defined:

```
def cummedian_stream(b):
    S=streamMedian()
    ret = []
    for item in b:
        S.insert(item)
        ret.append(S.getMedian())
    return np.array(ret)
```

Testing:

```
In [155]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,(5000))
In [156]: amed = cummedian_stream(a)
In [157]: np.allclose(cummedian_sorted(a), amed)
Out[157]: True
In [158]: timeit cummedian_sorted(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 781 ms per loop
In [159]: timeit cummedian_stream(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 39.6 ms per loop
```

The `heapq` stream approach is way faster.

---

The list comprehension that `@Uriel` gave is relatively slow.  But if I substitute `np.median` for `statistics.median` it is faster than `@Divakar's` sorted solution:

```
def fastloop(a):
    return np.array([np.median(a[:i+1]) for i in range(len(a))])

In [161]: timeit fastloop(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 360 ms per loop
```

And `@Paul Panzer's` partition approach is also good, but still slow compared to the streaming class.

```
In [165]: timeit cummedian_partition(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 391 ms per loop
```

(I could copy the `streamMedian` class to this answer if needed).

Comment: Yep, not even `numpy` can make an `O(n^2)` (or worse) algorithm faster than an -- what is it -- `O(n log n)` one or even better?

Answer (score 2):

Use `statistics.median` and cummulative list comprehension (note that odd indices contains medians of even-length lists - where the median is the average of the two median elements, so it usually results with a decimal and not an integer):

```
>>> from statistics import median
>>> arr = [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
>>> cum_median = [median(arr[:i+1]) for i in range(len(arr)-1)]
>>> cum_median
[1, 2.0, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.0]
```

Comment: without open cycles and comprehension

Comment: `np.median` is much faster in this role than `statistics.median`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there room for a late entry?

```
def cummedian_partition(a):
    n = len(a)
    assert n%4 == 0 # for simplicity
    mn = a.min() - 1
    mx = a.max() + 1
    h = n//2
    N = n + h//2
    work = np.empty((h, N), a.dtype)
    work[:, :n] = a
    work[:, n] = 2*mn - a[0]
    i, j = np.tril_indices(h, -1)
    work[i, n-1-j] = (2*mn - a[1:h+1])[j]
    k, l = np.ogrid[:h, :h//2 - 1]
    work[:, n+1:] = np.where(k > 2*l+1, mx, 2 * mn - mx)
    out = np.partition(work, (N-n//2-1, N-n//2, h//2-1, h//2), axis=-1)
    out = np.r_[2*mn-out[:, h//2: h//2-2:-1], out[::-1, N-n//2-1:N-n//2+1]]
    out[::2, 0] = out[::2, 1]
    return np.mean(out, axis=-1)
```

The algorithm uses partition which has linear complexity. Some gymnastics are required because `np.partition` does not support per-line split points. Combined complexity and memory required are quadratic.

Timings compared to current best:

```
for j in (100, 1000, 5000):
    a = np.random.randint(0, 100, (j,))
    print('size', j)
    print('correct', np.allclose(cummedian_partition(a), cummedian_sorted(a)))
    print('Divakar', timeit(lambda: cummedian_sorted(a), number=10))
    print('PP', timeit(lambda: cummedian_partition(a), number=10))

#  size 100
#  correct True
#  Divakar 0.0022412699763663113
#  PP 0.002393342030700296
#  size 1000
#  correct True
#  Divakar 0.20881508802995086
#  PP 0.10222102201078087
#  size 5000
#  correct True
#  Divakar 6.158387024013791
#  PP 3.437395485001616
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an approximated solution. if you treat the list `arr` of values as probability mass function. you can use the `np.cumsum(arr)` to get the cumulative distribution function. By definition, median is only for half of the probability.
which give you an approximated solution

```
arr[np.searchsorted(np.cumsum(arr), np.cumsum(arr)/2)]
```

Comment: I think this assumes that `arr` is already sorted, in which case you can simply look at index `i//2` for each `i`.