# Numpy expanding median implementation

Tags: pandas, numpy, median

wondering if anyone has a pure numpy implementation of

```
pandas.Series([1,2,3, ...]).expanding().median()
```

I searched posts but didn't find anything very succinct. Not sure if there's an elegant way to do this in numpy

Comment: This might be best implemented by a `for` loop.

Comment: Something like [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577059-running-median/#:~:text=Running%20Median%20%28Python%20recipe%29%20Maintains%20sorted%20data%20as,square-root%20of%20the%20window%20size.%20Python%2C%2094%20lines). Since I don't think vectorization would help in this case.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765586/numpy-calculate-cumulative-median. Lots of really knowledgable numpy users provided methods.